# Question on finitely presented algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Suppose $S$ is a finitely presented $R$-algebra. If $g:R[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to S$ is surjective, then $\ker(g)$ is finitely generated.

We can write $S$ as $R[y_1, \ldots, y_m]/(f_1,\ldots,f_t)$ and write $g$ as 
$g:R[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \to R[y_1, \ldots, y_m]/(f_1,\ldots,f_t)$, but I don't know how to find the kernel.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of the statement?

Comment: @MattN. Yeah, it seems to be an elementary question. But I can't manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stated and proved at http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00R2.

Comment: Hi, I am confused about the last step in the proof. It says that the kernel is the image of $(f_j, x_i - g_i)$ under $\psi$. It's obvious that the image of $(f_j, x_i - g_i)$ under $\psi$ is in the kernel, but why is the inverse direction correct ?

Comment: Oh, I know the reason now. Thanks very much.

Comment: It's unfortunate that these little bits get deleted, since I personally got stuck on the same thing: why is the kernel generated only by those elements? I'd appreciate a clear answer, left here for everyone that comes after me. Thank you in advance.